# First Isomorphism Theorem/use

Tags: exact-sequence, functors, derived-functors

How do I apply $T\varepsilon$ to obtain an isomorphism $\sigma_A:\text{coker}T(d_1)\to TA$ by the First Isomorphism Theorem in the snippet below?
In fact, I cannot see how FIT applies.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that $\text{coker} (Td_1) = TP_0 \big{/} \text{im}(Td_1)$. By exactness we have $\text{im}(Td_1) = \text{ker}(T_\epsilon)$, so $\text{coker} (Td_1) =TP_0 \big{/} \text{ker}(T_\epsilon) \overset{\sim}{\longrightarrow}\text{im}(T_\epsilon) = T_A$, since $T_\epsilon$ is surjective by exactness of the sequence at $T_A$.

Comment: How it follows that this is an isomorphism: $TP_0 \big{/} \text{ker}(T_\epsilon) \overset{\sim}{\longrightarrow}\text{im}(T_\epsilon)$ ?

Comment: This is the Fundamental theorem on homomorphisms : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_on_homomorphisms or as the author calls it: First Isom. theorem